# Why cookiecutter-django does not set DATABASE_URL and CELERY_BROKER_URL during entrypoint execution?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

cookiecutter-django does not set env variables for DATABASE_URL and CELERY_BROKER_URL during "entrypoint" file execution in local development environment.

After I manually 'exported' DATABASE_URL and CELERY_BROKER_URL they appeared in environment variables. Why is that?

By manually I mean I got inside the docker container then on the shell I wrote:

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}"
```

and

```
export CELERY_BROKER_URL="${REDIS_URL}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the environment variable `DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE` is set to `False` by default. Set it to `True` in your runtime environment and it will start reading the `.env` file and the `DATABASE_URL` in it:

```
export DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
```